# How to Trigger a batch file from php and how to get query string from url and pass that to batch file as argument?

Tags: php

Here is my batch file script I am running this script via task scheduler
By using the below script I am able to copy all files from invoice_feed folder to Network shared test folder (shared_folder) both servers are connecting via VPN

```
Echo off
net use \\windows_servername\test_folder shared_folder_password /user:shared_folder_username
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

If I want to copy a specific file to network shared folder then I am adding manually that file to the above batch script, it is working well. Below is the code

```
Echo off
net use \\windows_servername\test_folder shared_folder_password /user:shared_folder_username
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\file_to_copy.csv \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

Can I run this script by using PHP? If yes then can I pass dynamic value from URL and pass that in place of specific file name like below?

```
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\<?php echo $_GET['csv_file_name']?> \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

Or is there any other way instead of doing this in batch file I mean completely by using php?
I am trying to run the script like below

```
$file_name = $_GET['csv_file_name'];
echo exec('net use \\windows_servername\test_folder shared_folder_password /user:shared_folder_username');
echo exec('xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\$file_name \\windows_servername\\test_folder');
```

But no luck. It is showing 0 files copied. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/282806/should-i-impersonate-php-via-fastcgi